# get filenames with paths that match a basename pattern

Tags: grep, ls

I have a list of filenames with their paths like this

```
/some/path/or/another/RCrandomname.TRI
/another/path/NCrandomname2.TRI
/one/more/path/RCrandomname3.PCD
```

I would like to pick only the filenames (with their paths) whose basename starts with RC and have extension TRI
so in the above example I would like to get just

```
/some/path/or/another/RCrandomname.TRI
```

if I had the basename only I could do

```
ls | grep "^RC.*\.TRI$" > filenames
```

but here I have all the paths.
I have a requirement of using `ls`

Comment: `find . -type f -name 'RC*.TRI' > filenames`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have a requirement of using `ls`.

Comment: Then try `ls | grep -E '^(.*/)?RC[^/]*\.TRI$' > filenames`

Comment: `grep` does not remove anything, it only matches or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse output of `ls`, it is error prone in many ways.

You can use globbing with `shopt globstar`:

```sh
shopt -s globstar
ls -1 **/RC*.TRI > filenames
```

> `globstar`, When enabled, the globbing code treats `**` specially -- it matches all directories (and files within them, when appropriate) recursively.